# Spring boot component scan not working in maven multiple module project

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I followed spring official project [Creating a Multi Module Project](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-multi-module)'s guide, here is my project [Spring Cloud in Practice](https://github.com/jaggerwang/spring-cloud-in-practice). When I run one of the module with `./mvnw install && ./mvnw spring-boot:run -pl user`, it failed with the following log.

```
...
2019-12-20 13:33:58.886  INFO 8830 --- [  restartedMain] n.j.scip.user.api.ScipApplication        : Starting ScipApplication on jagger-mbp with PID 8830 (/Users/jagger/projects/jaggerwang/spring-cloud-in-practice/user/target/classes started by jagger in /Users/jagger/projects/jaggerwang/spring-cloud-in-practice/user)
2019-12-20 13:33:58.890  INFO 8830 --- [  restartedMain] n.j.scip.user.api.ScipApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-12-20 13:33:58.930  INFO 8830 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in /Users/jagger/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/Users/jagger/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar,file:/Users/jagger/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/txw2-2.3.2.jar,file:/Users/jagger/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar,file:/Users/jagger/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/stax-ex-1.8.1.jar,file:/Users/jagger/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar,file:/Users/jagger/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar
2019-12-20 13:33:58.930  INFO 8830 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2019-12-20 13:33:58.931  INFO 8830 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2019-12-20 13:33:59.109  WARN 8830 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
2019-12-20 13:33:59.235 ERROR 8830 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:156) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at net.jaggerwang.scip.user.api.ScipApplication.main(ScipApplication.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:203) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 12 common frames omitted

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  13.211 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-20T13:33:59+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If I supply a `ServletWebServerFactory` bean in configuration, it will complain other bean can not be found.

```java
...

    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletWebServerFactory() {
        return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    }

...
```

Here is my application:

```java
package net.jaggerwang.scip.user.api;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLWebsocketAutoConfiguration;
import net.jaggerwang.scip.user.api.config.ScipConfig;
import org.flywaydb.core.Flyway;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.DefaultApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.WebApplicationType;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "net.jaggerwang.scip.user",
        exclude = {GraphQLWebsocketAutoConfiguration.class})
@EntityScan("net.jaggerwang.scip.user.adapter.repository.jpa.entity")
@EnableJpaRepositories("net.jaggerwang.scip.user.adapter.repository.jpa")
@Slf4j
public class ScipApplication implements ApplicationRunner {
    public enum AppType {
        WEB, DB_MIGRATION
    }

    private static AppType appType = AppType.WEB;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var appArgs = new DefaultApplicationArguments(args);

        if (appArgs.getOptionValues("app.type") != null
                && !appArgs.getOptionValues("app.type").isEmpty()) {
            appType = AppType.valueOf(appArgs.getOptionValues("app.type").get(0).toUpperCase());
        }

        new SpringApplicationBuilder(ScipConfig.class)
                .web(appType == AppType.WEB ? WebApplicationType.SERVLET : WebApplicationType.NONE)
                .run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        if (appType == AppType.DB_MIGRATION) {
            migrateDatabase(args);
        }
    }

    private void migrateDatabase(ApplicationArguments args) {
        var flyway = Flyway.configure().dataSource(dataSource).load();
        flyway.migrate();

        log.info("Migrate database finished.");
    }
}
```

I'm also tried to use `@ComponentScan` directly, it has the same result.

Comment: One of Tomcat’s jars may have been corrupted by Maven when it downloaded them. Try clearing Maven’s cache and rebuilding your application.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to related with using `SpringApplicationBuilder` in main class. If I change main class to the simplest one, it runs ok.

```java
package net.jaggerwang.scip.user.api;

import com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLWebsocketAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "net.jaggerwang.scip.user",
        exclude = {GraphQLWebsocketAutoConfiguration.class})
@EntityScan("net.jaggerwang.scip.user.adapter.repository.jpa.entity")
@EnableJpaRepositories("net.jaggerwang.scip.user.adapter.repository.jpa")
public class ScipApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ScipApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```